# Even "IF" part of this condition is true, Only else part is being executed. Whatever the input is, Only Else executes

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

**Here is my code**

```
inputUSer=input('''
    Please Select The Mode you want to operate The script AS:
    1:  You selected-1 \n
    2:  You selected-2 \n
    3:  You selected-3\n
    4:  You selected-4 \n
''')

if inputUSer==1:
    print("You selected-1")


elif inputUSer==2:
    print("You selected-2")

elif inputUSer== 3:
    print("You selected-3")

elif inputUSer== 4:
    print("You selected-4")

else :
    print("OOPS! Seems like you entered the wrong Input")
```

I checked all the indentation and it's correct. I am new to python and a Noob.
Please Help me...
Thank you...

Comment: The value returned by `input` in Python 3.x is always a string. So, it is never `1` though it might be `'1'`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `input()` is a `str`, it'll never be equal to `1,2,3,4` as their as `ints`, you need to convert input

```
inputUSer = int(input('''
    Please Select The Mode you want to operate The script AS:
    1:  You selected-1 \n
    2:  You selected-2 \n
    3:  You selected-3\n
    4:  You selected-4 \n
'''))
```

Or change all the `if` to compare to a `str`

```
if inputUSer == '1':
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your input into an int()

```
inputUSer=int(input('''
    Please Select The Mode you want to operate The script AS:
    1:  You selected-1 \n
    2:  You selected-2 \n
    3:  You selected-3\n
    4:  You selected-4 \n
'''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Return value of `input` is a string. You might want to cast it to an integer using `int` function. Or you can change your `if` conditions to compare `inputUSer` with strings instead.